# Angular injects the view but does not bind

Tags: angularjs

in Index.html i defined:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="bwp">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="app/landingController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In app.js i defined:

```
var app = angular.module("bwp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(
        '/main', {
            templateUrl: 'app/test.html',
            controller: 'testController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/main' });
});
```

Here is the complete testController.js:

```
(function() {
   var app = angular.module("bwp");
   var landingController = function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = "this is a test";
};

app.controller("landingController", landingController);

}());
```

In test view I defined:

```
<h1 ng-controller="landingController">
{{test}}
</h1>
```

When i render the page i get (through inspect element):

```
<h1 ng-controller="landingController" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
{{test}}
</h1>
```

- Note that it identifies the controller and the scope.

SO...Angular injects the view but doesn't bind  $scope.test as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's your testController definition? What do you mean "in test controller I defined"? You can't add extra controllers/directives/services to angular after it's been bootstrapped(e.g. from within your controller)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I updated the code. What i meant is that in a separate file testController.js I defined the controller. So what is the right way to do that?

Comment: That controller is registered as "landingController" - you still don't have a "testController", which is what you're asking for in the route. Check out one of angular's routing examples - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: @Sacho is right, also you are mispelling your controllers/files. You are loading an script called _"landingController.js"_, but it's real name as you wrote it is _"testController.js"_. So you have 3 errors:
**1)** script tag should be "testController.js"
**2)** in your route you should've defined "landingController"
**3)** you shouldn't want to declare ng-controller in your partial (test view) since you already declared it in your route provider.

Comment: Yes I fixed all that. Here is a working version (with slightly different names) http://plnkr.co/edit/uAjrIRDXtgdlF1fJHecd?p=preview